# Backbone pubsub - global event not triggering inside default route on page load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, publish-subscribe

I have created a pubSub object with Backbone like so:

```
App.Vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

I have also created a router, which triggers a global event on the default uri: `http://localhost/`

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'default',
    },

    default: function() {
        App.Vent.trigger('contactsTable:show');
    }
});

App.Views.ContactsTable = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize: function() {
        App.Vent.on('contactsTable:show', this.updateApp, this);
    },

    updateApp: function() {
        console.log( 'Show All Contacts' );
    }

});

new App.Router;
Backbone.history.start();
new App.Views.ContactsTable;
```

The method `default` is successfully called but the event(`contactsTable:show`) **inside** the method does **not** get triggered.

However, if I load the page initially on say: `http://localhost/#contacts` and then navigate back to `http://localhost/` from there, the event **does** get triggered inside the router method.

I cannot figure  out why this may be. I need an event to be triggered on the default route regardless of whether or not it is the first route when the application is opened.

Comment: How do you know the event isn't triggered? Are you sure you're binding your listener *before* the `default` router is called?

Comment: Thank you, you were on right right issue. I was binding the listener before instantiating the router and calling `Backbone.history.start()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, my problem was that the `router` and `Backbone.history.start()` were being called *before* binding the event listener in my view.

This was happening because my view (which contains the listener) was being instantiated *inside the callback function of an AJAX request* and the `Router` and `Backbone.history.start()` was executed before the server returned a response.

This is the working code I have now after defining my models, views collections and router:

```
var contactsCollection = new App.Collections.Contacts();
contactsCollection.fetch().then(function() {

    var contactsTableView = new App.Views.ContactsTable({
        collection: contactsCollection
    });

    new App.Router;
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

The listener inside my view now responds to the event on initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is nothing in App.Vent is binds to 'contactsTable:show', please add following line and check if you see the message in console.

```
App.Vent.bind("contactsTable:show", function(){
    console.log('Inside - contactsTable:show');
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question to show the view I am using, which shows how the event is being listened for in my app.

Comment: Please change Vent.on to Vent.bind  App.Vent.bind('contactsTable:show', this.updateApp, this);

Comment: What is the benefit or reason for using `bind` instead of `on` when listening for events?